Имя "InitializeComponent" не существует в текущем контексте, при этом компиляция успешна
Я пишу своё приложение на WPF в Visual Studio 2022. В моём проекте при создании не было ошибки "Имя InitializeComponent не существует в текущем контексте", но спустя время она появилась, при этом компилируется успешно и приложение выполняет свою работу. Также он не видит элементы WPF. Как это исправить?

ПКМ по проекту - "Очистить", затем "Пересобрать". Если не помогает, то закрыть студию (или выгрузить проект), зайти в папку с проектом и удалить там все, что не относится к вашему коду, а именно bin, obj, .vs (или др. папки вашей IDE, например, .idea если Rider), файл .user, и т.д. После чего открыть проект и проделать все то, что сказал в начале.

Помогает:
Открыть "Свойства" => "Общие" => снять галочку "Включите WPF для этого проекта" => и поставить по новой.
